# how to put image and content side by side

Tags: html, css

```
<article>
  <h2 id="aboutme">About me </h2>
  <p>I currently studying design and coding in Nanyang Polytechnic . I also have
  passion or gaming</p>
  <img src="index.images/rainbow%20six%20siege.jpg" class="image2"/>
</article>
<aside>
  <h2>.skills</h2>
  <div id="image2">
    <img src="index.images/skill.jpg"/>
  </div>
</aside>
```

I'm still new to coding, pardon me. I need help on styling them to look like the ones in the image:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsQj4.jpg

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpjxse6L/ This fiddle can help

Answer (score 1):

You can just copy and paste this code. It will work. [Here's the Example](https://jsfiddle.net/61ohx3bm/)

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<h1 class="text-center">Hi I'm Owen</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <h2>About me</h2>
  </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
     <h2>.skills</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <img src="index.images/rainbow%20six%20siege.jpg" class=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <p>I currently studying design and coding in Nanyang Polytechnic . I also have
passion or gaming</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <img src="index.images/skill.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Get started with bootstrap here -- http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Hope that helps! Cheers.

Comment: Glad I could help. If I answered your question, please mark it as answered.

Comment: but where is css if there is , i try putting it in my code it doesnt show the same as yours

Comment: I updated my answer to include the full code. Just copy and paste. But checkout [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) it's great for beginners.

Answer (score -1):

Very simple JSfiddle here with just what you need.

https://jsfiddle.net/8k5fLxsn/

HTML:

```
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&bg=0099ff&txtclr=ffffff&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300&fm=png">
<p>
    Text next to image. Put anything you want here.
</p>
```

CSS:

```
img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain what the`float` does, since this answer will not really help anybody with a more complex problem.